# QListWidget item index selected by default

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a QListWidget which has some item, and I have "Remove" button on my form which actually removes item from list(array object) and from QlistWidget.

"Add" button for add item into array obj and show it to QlistWidget and the problem is when i press remove without selecting any item from list, it takes the item at the lats index by default and remove it, and the QlistWidget didn't refresh when i press remove button.

i confused how to explain it, need to try the code first

this is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from paramiko import SSHException
import jtextfsm as textfsm
import ipaddress
import time

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.device_list = [] #object array
        self.setWindowTitle("Network Automation")
        ############################# Input IP

        # Device Type
        lb_device_list = QLabel(self)
        lb_device_list.setText('Device Type')
        self.cb_device_list = QComboBox(self)
        self.cb_device_list.addItem('cisco_ios')
        self.cb_device_list.addItem('cisco_s300')

        # Ip Device
        lb_ip = QLabel(self)
        lb_ip.setText('IP Address')
        self.le_ip = QLineEdit(self)
        self.le_ip.setText('')
        self.le_ip.setPlaceholderText('Input Device IP')
        self.le_ip.setFixedWidth(150)

        # username
        lb_username = QLabel(self)
        self.le_username = QLineEdit(self)
        lb_username.setText('Username')
        self.le_username.setText('')
        self.le_username.setPlaceholderText('Input Username')
        self.le_username.setFixedWidth(150)

        # password
        lb_password = QLabel(self)
        self.le_password = QLineEdit(self)
        lb_password.setText('Password')
        self.le_password.setText('')
        self.le_password.setPlaceholderText('Input Password')
        self.le_password.setFixedWidth(150)

        # Privilage Password
        lb_enable = QLabel(self)
        lb_enable.setText('Privilege Mode Password')
        self.le_enable = QLineEdit(self)
        self.le_enable.setText('')
        self.le_enable.setPlaceholderText('Input Enable Password')
        self.le_enable.setFixedWidth(150)

        #button generate and add
        btgenerate = QPushButton(self)
        btgenerate.setText('Generate')
        btgenerate.setFixedWidth(70)
        btadd = QPushButton(self)
        btadd.setText('Add')

        #button delete
        btdel = QPushButton(self)
        btdel.setFixedWidth(70)
        btdel.setText('Remove')

        # line
        line = QFrame(self)
        line.setFrameShape(QFrame.VLine)
        line.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)
        line.setLineWidth(3)

        ########################### Layout Ip Device List

        lb3 = QLabel(self)
        lb3.setText('IP Device List')
        self.ip_device_list = QListWidget(self)
        self.ip_device_list.setFixedWidth(150)
        #self.combobox_ip_list = QComboBox(self)
        #self.combobox_ip_list.setFixedWidth(170)

        ############################## SubLayout and Layout
        hblayout = QHBoxLayout()
        hblayout.addWidget(btgenerate)
        hblayout.addWidget(btadd)

        sublayout = QVBoxLayout()
        sublayout.addWidget(lb_device_list)
        sublayout.addWidget(self.cb_device_list)
        sublayout.addWidget(lb_ip)
        sublayout.addWidget(self.le_ip)
        sublayout.addWidget(lb_username)
        sublayout.addWidget(self.le_username)
        sublayout.addWidget(lb_password)
        sublayout.addWidget(self.le_password)
        sublayout.addWidget(lb_enable)
        sublayout.addWidget(self.le_enable)
        sublayout.addLayout(hblayout)

        sublayout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        sublayout2.addWidget(lb3)
        sublayout2.addWidget(self.ip_device_list)
        #sublayout2.addWidget(self.combobox_ip_list)
        sublayout2.addWidget(btdel)
        sublayout2.addStretch(1)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addLayout(sublayout,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(line,0,1)
        layout.addLayout(sublayout2,0,2)

        btadd.clicked.connect(self.addDevice)

        btdel.clicked.connect(self.remove)



    ####################----------- AddDevice
    def addDevice(self):
        try:
            ip = self.le_ip.text()
            ipaddress.ip_address(ip)
            device_type = str(self.cb_device_list.currentText())
            username = self.le_username.text()
            password = self.le_password.text()
            secret = self.le_enable.text()
            command = 'show tech'
            self.device_list.append(MyClass(device_type, ip, username, password, secret, command))

            # self.combobox_ip_list.addItem(ip)# Add Ip to ComboBox
            self.ip_device_list.addItem(ip)

            self.le_ip.clear()
            self.le_username.clear()
            self.le_password.clear()
            self.le_enable.clear()
            #self.ip_device_list.clear()
            for list in self.device_list:
                print(list.ip,list.device_type)
        except ValueError:
            print("insert you're ip correctly")

    def remove(self):
        index = self.ip_device_list.currentRow()
        self.ip_device_list.takeItem(index)
        del self.device_list[index] #dremove data from list/array



class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, device_type=None, ip=None, username=None, password=None, secret=None, command=None):
        self.device_type = device_type
        self.ip = ip
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.secret = secret
        self.command = command


##################################
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.processEvents()
app.setStyle('cleanlooks')
window = Widget()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the [currentRow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#currentRow-prop) method will return `-1` if no selection is made. `-1` has a very specific meaning in Python indexing. It means last element (`-2` would mean element prior to last). So to solve your problem just add the following to your code:

```
def remove(self):
    index = self.ip_device_list.currentRow()
    if index != -1:
        self.ip_device_list.takeItem(index)
        del self.device_list[index]
```